# How to: Create a Visual Studio External Command that opens a browser *INSIDE* Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I currently have an external command that navigates to a specified URL by openuing an external default browser.

How can I get the browser to open within Visual Studio on a tab, similar to the way that the Start Page displays web content and can be used as a browser once opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: How to: Create a Visual Studio External Command that opens a browser *INSIDE* Visual Studio?

A: You can't